# Variable undefined when using .get()

Tags: node.js, discord

I am coding a Discord bot and one of my features is a Member counter. So far I can point it in the right direction and as long as I use the actual id number is numerical form everything works fine. The moment I try to create and store the id in a variable however, it starts to tell me that it is undefined.

```
    let setchan = ""
    let guildid = 0

    client.on('message', async message => {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix2) || message.author.bot) return;
const args = message.content.slice(prefix2.length).trim().split(" ");
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
if (command === 'memchan'){
    setchan = args
    message.channel.send("Channel set to: " + setchan)
} else if (command === 'count') {
    total = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id).memberCount   
    guildID = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id)
    message.channel.send("Current member count: " + total)
    message.channel.send("Your server id is: " + guildID)
    message.channel.send("Your channel id is set to: " + setchan)
    message.guild.channels.cache.get(setChan).setName("Members: " + total)
}
```

});
works fine

```
    message.guild.channels.cache.get(setchan).setName("Members: " + total)
```

Does not though.
I have used .toString() and tried to set it as a number instead of string. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Created the variable as both num and string.

the error I am getting is: Cannot read property 'setname' of undefined.

Comment: `setchan` is an empty string which you never assign. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry failed to mention I set the Setchan in a command before hand, just showing how my vars are set up

Comment: then clearly it's not being set to the correct value. Have you tried `console.log(setchan)` before trying to get the channel from cache to verify the value in it? This is extremely relevant to your problem so showing the other command and what scope `setchan` actually is in would help a lot.

Comment: Added the rest of my code to show how I set the "setchan' var

Comment: it prints the id just fine when I execute, but when I use a varible it wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your approach.

1. The declaration of `setchan` is *inside* your command handler. This means that every time the command handler is executed (once per message) it is re-set to "". If you change this value in one execution of the command handler, it will not persist to any other execution.
2. Even if this were working properly, you are setting `setchan = args`. `args` is the result of a `.split(" ")` - it is an *array* of arguments, not just one. You need to get `args[0]` if you want to respect only the first argument.
3. This is a poor way to implement any kind of configuration variables. When your bot restarts, the current memory state is lost. Since you're holding these only in memory, that means users will need to run `memchan` again every time the bot restarts. Additionally, if your bot ever joins more than just one guild, users in each guild will overwrite other guilds configuration.

My recommendation: Ditch the current approach. What you should do is either **store configuration data in a map** (object, Map, etc) and **write that map to disk** as JSON, loading it from disk on startup, so that the data can persist between restarts - or **use a proper database**, either a RDBMS/ORM/other. Look into SQL databases, Mongo, sequelize, etc.

---

To fix your current approach: the `setchan` variable needs to be declared *once* at the beginning of the file. You can store it on the bot if you like, it is quite convenient to do so.

```
//top level
bot.setchan = ""

...

//in memchan command
bot.setchan = args[0]

//in count command
message.guild.channels.cache.get(bot.setchan).setName("Members: " + total)
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I am trying to teach myself as I go. It has been a rough road so far, obviously.

Comment: @King96 It always is. If you have any questions about the above advice I'd be happy to clarify.

Comment: let setchan = args[0] solved my mess of an issue, but like mentioned above, there are better ways to do what I am doing.Thanks Klaycon

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I eventually worked it out without needing to store the channel id in a DB ( Iam trying to avoid any extra weight if I can). So instead of creating a variable I just pass the desired channels id as an arg. A user can then use their choice of already running mod bots like mee6, dyno, carl etc to use an automessage to tell my bot when to work.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix2) || message.author.bot) return;
const args = message.content.slice(prefix2.length).trim().split(" ");
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
if (command === 'run') {
    let setchan = args[0]
    total = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id).memberCount   
    message.channel.send("Current member count: " + total)
    message.guild.channels.cache.get(setchan).setName("Members: " + total)
    message.delete()
}
```

});

Then deletes the command (as I havent added a role check yet)...
Thank you kuso and klay!